# What is the difference between increment operator(++) and addition (+) operator?

Tags: c

What is the difference between increment operator `++` and an addition `+` operator?  Why can't we can use `+` instead of `++`?

What are the advantages of `++`/`--` operators over `+`/`-`? Where exactly are they applicable?

Comment: ++ modifies the object it is applied to. And, yes, it's unary as well...

Comment: It's less of an issue in C nowadays, and the choice of `++` is mostly stylistic. In C++, it makes a big difference since some containers overload only `++` and not `+`.

Answer (score 4):

x++;

v.s.

```
x = x + 1;
```

The main advantage comes from pre-increment v.s. post increment:

e.g.

```
x = 1;
y = 1;

a = x + 1; // a is 2, x  is 1  - e.g. does not modify x

a = ++x;   // a is 1, x is 2
b = y++;   // b is 2, y is 2
```

The major downside is that stuff like

```
a = ++x + x--;
```

is undefined behavior. Completely compiler dependent and WILL make life hell for anyone trying to figure out the "bug".

Comment: I think this is wrong, that you have switched post and pre increment https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Answer (score 2):

The only difference that is given by the C standard is the number of evaluations of `x`. For normal variables the difference usually doesn't matter. If the compiler can prove that in `x = x + 1` the two evaluations of `x` should give the same value it might optimize this out.

If `x` is e.g declared volatile or involves the evaluation of a function, the evaluation *must* be done twice. Example:

```
unsigned* f(void);
```

then

```
*f() = *f() + 1;
```

is quite different from

```
++(*f());
```

Answer (score 2):

The unary operators (++, --) are mainly there for convenience - it's easier to write `x++` than it is to write `x = x + 1` for example.

`++` can also be used to do a 'pre-increment' or a 'post-increment'.  If you write `x++` then the value of `x` is increased and the original value of `x` is returned.  For example:

```
int a = 0;
int x = 0;
a = x++;  //  x is now equal to 1, but a is equal to 0.
```

If you write `++x`, x is still incremented, but the *new* value is returned:

```
int a = 0;
int x = 0;
a = ++x;  //  Both a and x now equal 1.
```

There is also usually a minor difference in the compiler's implementation as well.  Post-increment (`x++`) will do something like this:

- Create a temporary variable
- Copy `x` to the temporary variable
- Increment `x`
- Return the temporary variable

Whereas pre-increment (`++x`) will do something like this:

- Increment `x`
- Return `x`

So using pre-increment requires less operations than post-increment, but in modern day systems this usually makes no worthwile difference to be a decent way of optimising code.

Answer (score 0):

`++` is a convenience syntax.  It does not really add capability to the language, but it adds a way of writing some common operations more concisely.

As a standalone statement `a++;` is identical to `a+=1;` is identical to `a=a+1`;

`a++` can be useful in some situations that would otherwise need two statements:

`while (a < N) doSomethingWith(a++);`

is just a shorter form of

```
while (a<N) 
{
   doSomethingWith(a); 
   a=a+1;
}
```

I don't think there is anything you can write with an `a++` that you couldn't also write with an `a=a+1`, but you can't just do a 1 for 1 substitution. Sometimes the 2nd form will require more code to be equivalent, since the 1st performs two things: produce the value of `a`, and then increment `a`.  The `a=a+1` form produces the value of `a` after the increment, so if you need the original value, you need a separate statement to process that first.

Comment: It's actually not syntactic sugar, because there's not always a way to "de-sugar" the operation without introducing additional sequence points.

Comment: Ok.  Reworded to be clearer.  It's not purely equivalent, but neither is it strictly needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could in fact use addition:

```
a = a + 1
```

But most people prefer the shorter version. In some languages it actually avoids the need to copy the value to a new location, but as nneonneo has helpfully pointed out, the C compiler is likely to optimise this for you.

Comment: Modern C compilers are probably going to optimize `a=a+1` into `a++`.

Answer (score 0):

"++" means "plus one"
eg

```
int x = 5;
x++;  // the same as x = x + 1
cout << x; // will print 6
```

"+" is the known plus operator

Answer (score 0):

The difference between using the increment operator(ie. value++) vs using the addition operator(ie. value + 1) is that the first one sometimes can cause mutation especially if we are accessing a global variable inside a function;

Using increment operator.

```js
// The global variable
var fixedValue = 4;

function incrementer () {
  // Only change code below this line

  return fixedValue ++;
  // Only change code above this line
}
var newValue = incrementer(); // Should equal 5
console.log(fixedValue); // Should print 5
```

Using addition operator.

```js
// The global variable
var fixedValue = 4;

function incrementer () {
  // Only change code below this line

  return fixedValue + 1;
  // Only change code above this line
}
var newValue = incrementer(); // Should equal 5
console.log(fixedValue); // Should print 4
```

Answer (score -1):

increment doing on register  but addition do by ALU we can use + instead of  increment  but increment  is faster

Comment: Wrong.  Both can use the same instructions.

Comment: no it is not same you thing it is same but do by different hardware in cpu

Comment: Both can use the *same instructions.*  If the instructions are the same, then the hardware will interpret them the same.  The compiler does not do anything special with the increment operation, it is equivalent to addition.

Comment: you can search my told in Computer_Organization__Design__and_Architecture it for hardware engineer

Comment: This has nothing to do with the hardware, this is about the compiler.  The compiler will generate the same assembly code for both.  The CPU doesn't get a choice in the matter.

Comment: no not same in this link is the list of asm instruction you can see it is not same [asm list X86 and X64](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64-abc.html)

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur: Experiment: `echo 'main(){int x=0;x++;}' | gcc -xc - -S -o- > a.s ; echo 'main(){int x=0;x=x+1;}' | gcc -xc - -S -o- > b.s ; diff a.s b.s`. On my machine, there *are no differences*. The compiler treats these two statements the *exact same way*, so the hardware must too.

Comment: you should not sense any difference in high level compiler if you write program an assembly that time seance it a lot if you want know more about this you must read book like Computer_Organization__Design__and_Architecture

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur: This is not a question about assembly, this is a question about C.

Comment: yes but c at first compile to assembly then compile assembly to  machine code

Comment: But the assembly is the same, so the machine code is the same too.

Comment: I think Introduce enough resource for it. use machine code debugger  and  debug c output you can see it but if you want i can explain more about Detail of this instruction a to z